# Edge of the Empire -- what Sith exist in this period?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars

Does anyone know where I can find a good resource to see the generally agreed upon living sith/jedi in the edge of the empire time period?  I suppose the game justifies that there are living, trained force-users outside of the movies, and I wonder if there are any popular sources of lore that paints some of these characters.

Perhaps a peaceful Jedi family hiding on a forest planet, or a team of Sith assassins hounding out the resistance leaders. Or are there agents of the darkside operating openly, flanked by elite stormtroopers. Either way, designing the hierarchy, I'm looking for a good resource outlining extant Sith/Jedi (trained force users) during this period.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because RPG.SE [only handles setting research questions that are RPG-specific](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/3276/4398), but [scifi.se] should be able to help you!

Comment: BESW is spot on, if you are asking what guidelines exist in the published EOTE materials from FFG that would be on topic, but general setting questions are best handled by a stack exchange focused on that topic.